# PHP Function "... Days Ago" In "While Loop" Doesn't Work

Tags: php

I want to add a description of the posting time for each of my articles on the homepage. So there are some content published at different times, and I want to make it appear clearer by adding a description of the date of publication.

But I found a complicated problem. In my code example below, it produces the wrong time. I have tried several times but failed. Can I still fix this with this code or maybe there is another code that is more perfect.

**PHP CODE:**

```
$sql = $DBcon->query("SELECT content, post_date FROM article");
$row = $sql->fetch_array();
$post_date = $row['post_date']; // 2019-06-01 16:29:07

function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}

do {
// .......

echo $row['content'];
echo time_elapsed_string( $post_date );

// .......
} while ($row = $sql->fetch_array());
```

The above code produces the same time for all content. Even though my content was made at different times. Obviously this is something wrong. So how do you fix it?

Comment: Because you only define `$post_date` once outside of your loop so that value never changes. Your while loop also does nothing.

Comment: @JohnConde then, how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line:

```
$post_date = $row['post_date']; // 2019-06-01 16:29:07
```

inside of the `do ... while` loop or, as shown below, remove the variable completely.

```
do {
// .......

echo $row['content'];
echo time_elapsed_string($row['post_date']);

// .......
} while ($row = $sql->fetch_array());
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try following way:**

```
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['content'];
    }
```

**For Loop:** You need to use a condition in while loop.
Here is 5 example about while loop. Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp